# ffmpeg -master_pl_name grabbing the correct codec

Tags: ffmpeg, manifest, http-live-streaming

I am using the following ffmpeg command to generate my hls playlist with the FFmpeg option -master_pl_name set.

```
ffmpeg -i becky.mov \
-i becky.mov \
-i becky.mov \
-i becky.mov \
-s:v:0 1920x1080 -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 4000k \
-s:v:1 1280x720 -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 2000k \
-s:v:2 854x480 -c:v:2 libx264 -b:v:2 1000k \
-s:v:3 640x360 -c:v:3 libx264 -b:v:3 600k \
-c:a:0 copy \
-map 0:a -map 0:v -map 1:v -map 2:v -map 3:v \
-var_stream_map "a:0,agroup:audio v:0,agroup:audio v:1,agroup:audio v:2,agroup:audio v:3,agroup:audio" \
-threads 0 -f hls -movflags frag_keyframe -hls_flags single_file+independent_segments \
-hls_segment_type fmp4 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_allow_cache 1 \
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 -y burnt/demo2/list_%v/master.m3u8
```

This is fine and will give me a master.m3u8 file that looks like this.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1047200,RESOLUTION=640x272,CODECS="avc1.4d4815,mp4a.40.2"
pl_0.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1788600,RESOLUTION=842x358,CODECS="avc1.4d481e,mp4a.40.2"
pl_1.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3436400,RESOLUTION=1280x544,CODECS="avc1.4d481f,mp4a.40.2"
pl_2.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=6096200,RESOLUTION=1920x816,CODECS="avc1.4d4828,mp4a.40.2"
pl_3.m3u8
```

The problem that I have is I need to generate my master.m3u8 file manually as I am also generating subtitles and audio description groups. I am using ffprobe to do this.

But I am not sure how to get the CODECS="avc1.4d4815,mp4a.40.2" value to then insert it into my master.m3u8 file.

My ffprobe output doesn't seem to give any of that information here is the full output.

```
{
    "streams": [{
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1001/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[27][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x001b",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 272,
            "coded_width": 640,
            "coded_height": 272,
            "has_b_frames": 2,
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 21,
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "false",
            "nal_length_size": "0",
            "r_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "avg_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "time_base": "1/90000",
            "start_pts": 7508,
            "start_time": "0.083422",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "variant_bitrate": "800000"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
            "profile": "LC",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[15][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x000f",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 2,
            "channel_layout": "stereo",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/90000",
            "start_pts": 5588,
            "start_time": "0.062089",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "variant_bitrate": "800000"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 2,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1001/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[27][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x001b",
            "width": 842,
            "height": 358,
            "coded_width": 848,
            "coded_height": 368,
            "has_b_frames": 2,
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 30,
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "false",
            "nal_length_size": "0",
            "r_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "avg_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "time_base": "1/90000",
            "start_pts": 7508,
            "start_time": "0.083422",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "variant_bitrate": "1400000"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 3,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
            "profile": "LC",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[15][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x000f",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 2,
            "channel_layout": "stereo",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/90000",
            "start_pts": 5588,
            "start_time": "0.062089",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "variant_bitrate": "1400000"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 4,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1001/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[27][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x001b",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 544,
            "coded_width": 1280,
            "coded_height": 544,
            "has_b_frames": 2,
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 31,
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "false",
            "nal_length_size": "0",
            "r_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "avg_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "time_base": "1/90000",
            "start_pts": 7508,
            "start_time": "0.083422",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "variant_bitrate": "2800000"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 5,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
            "profile": "LC",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[15][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x000f",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 2,
            "channel_layout": "stereo",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/90000",
            "start_pts": 5588,
            "start_time": "0.062089",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "variant_bitrate": "2800000"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 6,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1001/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[27][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x001b",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 816,
            "coded_width": 1920,
            "coded_height": 816,
            "has_b_frames": 2,
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 40,
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "false",
            "nal_length_size": "0",
            "r_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "avg_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "time_base": "1/90000",
            "start_pts": 7508,
            "start_time": "0.083422",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "variant_bitrate": "5000000"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 7,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
            "profile": "LC",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[15][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x000f",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 2,
            "channel_layout": "stereo",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/90000",
            "start_pts": 5588,
            "start_time": "0.062089",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "variant_bitrate": "5000000"
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "master.m3u8",
        "nb_streams": 8,
        "nb_programs": 4,
        "format_name": "hls",
        "format_long_name": "Apple HTTP Live Streaming",
        "start_time": "0.062089",
        "duration": "169.180238",
        "size": "575",
        "bit_rate": "27",
        "probe_score": 100
    }
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks